# Numpy Runtime Warning causing Apache Workers to freeze in "Sending Reply" state

Tags: django, apache, numpy, mod-wsgi

Recently, I was tracking down an elusive bug in my code. It came down to some numpy code that computes the mean of a part of an array.

```
np.array(X[X == i]).mean(0)
```

Of course, if there are no elements in `X` with a value of `i` then previous code is equivalent to calculating the mean of an empty array.

```
np.array([]).mean(0)
```

This results in the value `nan`. But on some architectures, it also results in this warning.

> RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars

We fixed the code and everything works great now, but there is another part of this story that is a bit more troubling.

The way that the bug was manifest was that it caused Apache processes to seize up with every worker stuck in the "Sending Reply" state. The workers that were caught in the "Sending Reply" were not the actual worker that caused the problem, but those that followed immediately after it. No python exceptions were raised, memory usage was fine, and the CPU was barely being used. It just slowly crippled Apache until it become completely unresponsive.

[image]

We use Apache, Django, mod_wsgi, and numpy among other things.

Any ideas on why this numpy code caused Apache to seize up? I would like to take action to prevent it in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See:

- http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ApplicationIssues#Python_Simplified_GIL_State_API

From memory numpy is affected by a variant of that issue. Ensure you force the WSGI application to run in the main interpreter context.

Answer (score 2):

Building from @Graham Dumpleton answer, just adding this line:

```
WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
```

to my application's apache config file fixed the issue for me.